# How does Rust handle functions with "..." at the end of args?

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
pub type f_t =
    ::std::option::Option<extern "C" fn(a: ::std::os::raw::c_int, ...)>;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub f: f_t,
}

fn main() {
}
```

It does not compile because there is no default `Clone` implementation for functions with "..." at the end of args.

1. How does Rust handle this "..." at the end of line, does it do the same thing as "..." in C?
2. Rust can not compile this code, but if I comment `, ...`, it compiles fine. What is the difference, why does one class of function pointers implement `Clone` while the other does not?
3. How should I implement `Clone` for such functions?

Comment: These are called [*variadic functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It means approximately the same as it does in C. Rust does not have native variadic functions (you cannot implement one in Rust itself), but it supports the syntax as a special case for binding to C functions.
2. Rust does not know what the real signature of the C function is. So you can declare it as whatever you want, but if you get it wrong then calling the function will likely crash at runtime.
3. It's an unintentional omission, these function pointers are supposed to magically be `Clone`. On nightly and beta this is already fixed.